# Thingsboard How to get ${entityName} inside a 'Static Widget (inside a Dashboard State)'

Tags: static, widget, thingsboard

I'm trying to develop a widget based in the 'Static Widget'.

I can access almost everything using $injector:

```
var $injector = self.ctx.$scope.$injector;
var attributeService = $injector.get(self.ctx.servicesMap.get('attributeService'));
var assetService = $injector.get(self.ctx.servicesMap.get('assetService'));
```

What I don't know is how can I use this Widget in a 'State Dashboard' and get the ${entityName} inside it.

With the ${entityName} in the Widget I can get the 'entityID' and everything else:

```
assetService.findByName(entityName).subscribe((data) => {
    alert(data.id.id);
});
```

Edit 1:
Thanks Andreas. I can get the alias but can't go to the properties of the json because the widget doesn't recognized them whem I'm editing the widget.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09wQl.png)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the Devices associated to the current dashboard state in the resolvedAliases property following the route:

```
self.ctx.dashboard.aliasController.resolvedAliases
```

There you'll see all the declared dashboard alias by id, and it will look like this:

```
{
"45a04c6b-1d79-de23-...": {
    "alias": "vehiculos",
    "entityFilter": {
        ...
    },
    "stateEntity": false,
    "resolveMultiple": true,
    "currentEntity": null
},
"1b02f2a4-5a6c-2cf7-...": {
    "alias": "selectedvehicle",
    "entityFilter": {
        ...
    },
    "stateEntity": true,
    "resolveMultiple": false,
    "currentEntity": {
        "id": "1c90cf60-1a8c-11ee-...",
        "entityType": "DEVICE",
        "name": "equipo ensamble",
        "label": "equipo ensamble"
    }
}
```

}

The only prerequisite is to know your dashboard's aliases id. Those are in the route:

```
self.ctx.dashboard.aliasController.entityAliases
```

Which was 1b02f2a4-1a8c(...) for the current selected device in my case. Finally can take the Device name with:

```
self.ctx.dashboard.aliasController.resolvedAliases["1b02f2a4-5a6c-..."].currentEntity.name
```

Hope being helpful.